# "Up To Date" Gradle task status when it has no output

Tags: gradle

How can you correctly mark a Gradle task as being "up to date" when the task doesn't produce any output? The task should remain "up to date" provided the last run was successful and the inputs haven't changed since then. The Gradle guide states just before section [15.9.2](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10FD3), the following:

```
"A task with no defined outputs will never be considered up-to-date."
```

How is it possible to mark tasks as up to date in this case? It appears that Gradle needs to know the time of the last successful run and then compare that to the last modified time of the inputs. As a workaround the script could create / touch an empty file to mark the task as complete? Are there any other suggested workarounds?

Comment: The documentation has since changed so this exat quote is no longer present. The most recent change looks to be come from [this commit](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/655cbf2d0de02c499ea544e3fa5c451aed293a7d#diff-3c7e708f2e623215ccb37c9c0ae83eefL330).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To just think through the different scenarios...

- Tasks without any inputs or outputs.  These run all the time. This might be just wrapping an existing "do something" executable.
- Tasks with inputs **and** outputs.  These run when either the inputs or outputs change.  This might be a compiler.
- Tasks with just outputs. These run only when the outputs have changed/don't exist.  This might be something that downloads something. (I think these are pretty rare in reality, I'd count the URL to download as an input.)
- Tasks with inputs and no outputs.  I haven't run into these in practice.

Like you've said, you could cheat the up-to-date checks with an output file that is just empty. The built-in Gradle [Test](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) task is most similar to what you're describing and it has a "report" as its output.  I think you would probably have something similar too.  It could be as simple as capturing the stdout/stderr of the task and putting that into a file.  That's not too useful for when everything passes, but it would be useful for when things fail.

Of course, any of these could be supplemented with a custom `upToDateWhen` bit of code. e.g., you have a task that starts a webserver and it's "up-to-date" when the webserver is already running.  I don't think that's a good fit with what you're describing here.

To start out with, I'd try:

`outputs.files file("${buildDir}/reports/${name}.out")`

I think that'd work with or without actually putting something in the file.

Comment: Thanks @bigguy, I've implemented it as you suggested and it's working well.

Comment: A typical example of a task with inuts only is a verification task. I have an example where I verify that developers have not entered specific URLs, usernames or passwords in files to be delivered in a build. If found, we fail the build with an exception.
But I will add a 'report' as output, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I've run into this kind of task when executing tools that upload files (if download it only output then upload is only input). I've solved this by define the same files/dirs as both inputs and outputs.

Comment: Should a task be out of date if an output changed, but no inputs changed? For example if another task inadvertently modifies the output of another task or some manual editing happens?

Answer (score 5):

You can override the tasks `upToDateWhen` method.

```
task createDist(type: Zip) {
  outputs.upToDateWhen {
    return true
  }
}
```

So with true it is always up-of-date and false always out-of-date. You can define any kind of custom logic to determine if it is up to date.

Comment: The logic I want is that it's up to date if there was no error last time and the inputs haven't changed since then - I don't believe that I can easily write an upToDateWhen function for that. Gradle needs to know when the last successful run was, hence I'm thinking this can only be solved by a temp file. I thought Gradle would have a better answer for this type of situation.

Comment: Think I was a bit quick to answer last time. Gradle will run your task again if you don't change anything in the task, such as printing out info or similar. If you use default task such as the Zip task it already has outputs defined. If your task does change the state of the world then you should define the outputs as outputs of the task.

Comment: In this case, it just runs some unit tests and verifies that there are no failures - so there's no output file. Best I can think of is to add a "tests-ran.txt" that doesn't do anything.

Comment: ok, if you use the test task provided by the java plugin (or scala or groovy prob others too) it will be rerun if you change your src code, your test code and I think it also will be rerunned if you change the build.gradle file now (didn't use to do this). If you rerun the test without changing any of these it should be considered up-to-date

Comment: I'll also note, that this doesn't work. It will always run this task at least once, because gradle will run it if there's no "history." Kind of frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

> Tasks with inputs and no outputs

Unless you explicitly declare the output, Gradle will decide the output is out-of-date to stay build safe.

You should always patently declare both inputs and outputs.

Use `outputs.upToDateWhen { true }` to simultaneously declare outputs and indicate that your outputs are always up-to-date.

For example (in Kotlin):

```
task ("dataFileHandler") {
     inputs.file ("data-file.txt")
     outputs.upToDateWhen { true }
     doLast {
         // do something with "data-file.txt"
     }
}
```

This task will be executed once (on the first build) and will remain “UP-TO-DATA” until “data-file.txt” is changed.