# Gradle task modifying a file never up to date

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle file that is modifying a file by executing a command line.

I would like it to run only if file has been changed since its last run.

I can't find a way to do that. It seems to always consider that the file has changed and thus that the task is not up to date.

I am not sure it is similar to the case in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599011/up-to-date-gradle-task-status-when-it-has-no-output), because my task does have an output.

My task typically runs `perl -pi -e <regex>` on a file, which is part of the output of the build.

(I don't think I can use a `Copy` task for that, because that file is binary)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Up To Date" Gradle task status when it has no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599011/up-to-date-gradle-task-status-when-it-has-no-output)

Comment: What task type do you use? Could you post a code example?

Comment: @lu.koerfer thanks. I have added that info to the question

Comment: So you use an `Exec` task or the `exec` method? Did you try to register the file via `inputs.file(...)` or `outputs.file(...)` or even both (since the file is modified). Without a code example it's really hard to recreate your problem.

Comment: I use the exec method, but I don't think it makes much of a difference since that's the only thing my task does. I have tried setting only inputs and only outputs as well. I'll post code, but basically I have 2 tasks : one that unzips an archive, and the other that calls perl -pi -e <regex> on an unzipped file